# Como criar uma FUNCTION para formatar moeda no POSTGRE?

Tags: postgresql

Criei uma, porém, não deu certo olha aí:

```
CREATE FUNCTION formatar_moeda(valor FLOAT) RETURNS VARCHAR(15) AS
$$
   DECLARE
   formatado VARCHAR(15);
BEGIN
  SET formatado = NUMBER(valor,2);
  SET formatado = REPLACE(formatado,'.','#');
  SET formatado = REPLACE(formatado,',','.');
  SET formatado = REPLACE(formatado,'#',',');
  RETURN CONCAT('R$', formatado);
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: http://paposql.blogspot.com.br/2012/02/funcao-para-formatar-moeda-em-reais-no.html

Answer (score 1):

Podes fazer assim:

```
Select to_char(123.45, 'L9G999G990D99');
```

L - Símbolo da moeda

D - Ponto decimal

9 - Números

G - Separador de unidades

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda... vou tentar.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seja isso que você queria:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION formatar_moeda(valor FLOAT) 
  RETURNS VARCHAR(15) AS
$body$
DECLARE
--------parametros--------
    pValor        ALIAS FOR $1;
--------variaveis---------
    vValor        VARCHAR;
BEGIN
    SELECT to_char(pValor, 'L9G999G990D99') INTO vValor;
RETURN vValor;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Daí você usa passando o valor por parâmetro assim:

```
SELECT formatar_moeda(123.45)
```

---

Conforme o [Pedro Luzio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/25680/pedro-luzio) explicou na outra resposta:

```
SELECT to_char(pValor, 'L9G999G990D99') INTO vValor;
```

L - Símbolo da moeda

D - Ponto decimal

9 - Números

G - Separador de unidades

Answer (score 0):

se quiser manter a idéia original, sem mudar a definição LC_CURRENCY para pt_BR pode usar o código abaixo

```js
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION formatar_moeda(valor REAL) RETURNS VARCHAR(100) AS
$$
   DECLARE
   formatado VARCHAR(100);
BEGIN
  SELECT  to_char(valor::float, '999G999G999D99') INTO formatado;
  SELECT REPLACE(formatado,'.','#') INTO formatado;
  SELECT REPLACE(formatado,',','.') INTO formatado;
  SELECT REPLACE(formatado,'#',',') INTO formatado;
  RETURN CONCAT('R$', formatado);
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```